# Why are the sound files for my project not loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm working on a drum kit using Javascript, CSS, and HTML, but my sounds are not loading. I checked the sources tab in Chrome developer tools and the sounds are not there but I have added them in my local directory. Could someone help me troubleshoot this? Here is the relevant js code:

```
var a =document.querySelector("div.set").addEventListener("click",function (){
var audio = new Audio("sounds\crash.mp3");
audio.play();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a folder `Drum Kit Starting Files` within another folder of the same name?

Comment: The file is not found. Are you sure the path is correct and that you don't want to pass a relative path like :"./sounds/crash.mp3" or something like that ?